# Old DotMatrix Printer(parallel port) to USB

Tags: usb, printer, parallel-port

I have [this](http://www.tvs-e.in/product.php?detid=15) printer. It has a 25 pin parallel port. To make it work with my pc,I purchased a Parallel to USB adapter. But nothing seems to work(the printer doesnt get detected)

I have tried setting the port to LPT1,2,3 and USB001,2,3.

Can anybody give suggestions on how to make it work, and to detect if everything is working fine or not?

Comment: You're probably in for some fun.  That printer won't be plug-and-play, so you will need to load a driver for it.  The driver will expect to see the printer on the missing parallel port.  The USB adapter probably creates some form of virtual parallel port that the printer driver may not be designed to recognize.  Add to that the fact that USB-connected printers expect the driver to be loaded before the printer is connected, while parallel printers work the other way around.  Tech support from the adapter manufacturer may be the place to start.

Comment: According to the site specifications, the printer has a USB interface (and drivers even for Linux and up to 64-bit Win7: http://www.tvs-e.in/drivers/MSP-Series/TVS-MSP-245-Win7-64bit.zip), so you might actually be ok to just plug it in via USB (no need for the adapter) and download/install the driver for your OS. Is this printer an older model without the USB-B plug?